# using lsqcurvefit to fit piece-wise linear

Tags: optimization, matlab, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I would like to use this function to fit piece-wise linearly to a set of data. Namely, I want to fit them with several linear segments.

Including other requirements, I would not want the segments are divided evenly along x-axis but are optimally divided along x-axis

My current problem is: I'm not sure if this MATLAB function support this. Also, if it does, how may I feed the function to function handle (MATLAB does not mention function handle if unlimit number of segments)

Thank you

Comment: When you say "optimally divided along the $x$-axis", do you mean you want the _data_ to determine where to put the boundaries between the segments?

Comment: yes. That's what I mean. It's the estimated/fitting function determines the boundary between two adjacent segments

Comment: One problem I see is this: You have finitely many observed $x$ values and for each $x$ value you have finitely many $y$ values.  If you put a boundary between segments between every pair of successive $x$ values, then you can probably make the line segment for each $x$ value match exactly the average $y$ value for that $x$ value.  If you had just one $y$ value for each $x$ value, this would fit every data point exactly.  Definitely over-fitting, and it would be the least-squares solution.

Comment: I can see your point. But probably, I forgot to add a condition that I would like to control the number of segments i.e. for N segments, the fitting is optimized